# Python: How to remove (replace with "") combinations of apostrophes and commas in Python strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like this which has some weird characters attached to the front (Entire thing is a string):

```
# Edited to make more clear. It is essentially this:

x = """
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:25.843 request id: app - xxxxxx
', "INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxxx
", 'INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.497 request id: app - xxxxxxxx
"""

# So need to remove the comma and apostrophes in the 2nd and 3rd line of string object x
```

I would like to remove the `', "` and `', "` from the 2nd and 3rd lines, but it is difficult to replace or regex it due to the combination of apostrophes creating `string literal is unterminated` errors.

Comment: Does each string have "INFO"? can you please confirm it?

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is replace anything/everything that precedes INFO. Is that so?

Comment: Where does this come from? The quotation is a bit weird.

Comment: @Nineteendo Was given to me as a poorly formatted API endpoint which yields a bunch of logs as a single string response object. I need to send it out to another place via websocket... Never have I imagined commas and apostrophes in strings would cause me this many issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each log line would always begin with some keyword like `INFO` or `DEBUG`, we can do a regex replacement on the text in multiline mode:

```py
logs = """INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:25.843 request id: app - xxxxxx
', \"INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxxx
\", 'INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.497 request id: app - xxxxxxxx"""

output = re.sub(r'^[^A-Z]+', '', logs, flags=re.M)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:25.843 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.497 request id: app - xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string_test = f"""INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:25.843 request id: app - xxxxxx
', "INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxxx
", 'INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.497 request id: app - xxxxxxxx"""

string_test = string_test.replace(f"'", "")
print(string_test)
```

How this works:
Replace every ' with nothing, removing it.

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that what you really want to do is remove anything/everything that precedes 'INFO' on any line then:

```
mystring = """INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:25.843 request id: app - xxxxxx
', "INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxxx
", 'INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.497 request id: app - xxxxxxxx"""

newstring = []

for line in mystring.splitlines():
    if (i := line.find('INFO')) >= 0:
        line = line[i:]
    newstring.append(line)

print('\n'.join(newstring))
```

**Output:**

```
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:25.843 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.407 request id: app - xxxxxx
INFO     2022-12-27 16:56:26.497 request id: app - xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The OP's input appears to be some log file, and a given line may start with something other than `INFO` (such as `DEBUG` or `ERROR`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did you notice the caveat written into the first line of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `str.replace()` method to remove all apostrophes from a string, e.g. `result = my_str.replace("'", '')`. The `str.replace()` method will remove all apostrophes from the string by replacing them with empty strings.

Comment: The poster also asked to remove commas.